# UISplitViewController Swipe On Detail Navigate Back And Forth

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisplitviewcontroller

Starting with the default SplitViewController project I added a swipe left and right gesture to the detail view. I defined a protocol that the master view implements when a swipe left or right occurs.

```
protocol SwipeDelegate: AnyObject {
    func onSwippedLeft()

    func onSwippedRight()
}
```

In the MasterViewController the onSwippedLeft() implementation advances the currently selected item by one:

```
func onSwippedLeft() {
        let currentRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row        
        if currentRow == objects.count - 1 {
            print("Already on first item")
            return
        }

        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: currentRow! + 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView!.selectRow(at: newIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.middle)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: newIndexPath)
    }
```

The problem occurs when I add the last line. Visually everything works; as I swipe left I see the selection on the tableview move forward; however, the last line I'm attempting to manually perform a selection so that as the selected item advances the detail view is replaced with contents for that item.

```
[MasterDetailDefault.MasterViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabe28084e0
2018-09-19 09:07:11.618683-0700 MasterDetailDefault[87530:2282523] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterDetailDefault.MasterViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabe28084e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011075929b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fcf5735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110777fa4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113e9b163 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011075dd14 ___forwarding___ + 772
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011075fe88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   MasterDetailDefault                 0x000000010f3c2971 $S19MasterDetailDefault0A14ViewControllerC13onSwippedLeftyyF + 2321
    7   MasterDetailDefault                 0x000000010f3c331e $S19MasterDetailDefault0A14ViewControllerCAA13SwipeDelegateA2aDP13onSwippedLeftyyFTW + 30
```

What is my error here?

**UPDATE 1**

I ran the code today without haven't touched anything and this crash no longer happens. I removed the last line as suggested:

```
self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: newIndexPath)
```

and replaced it with firing the segue manually:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
```

Now here is the weird part. On iPad everything works as expected now, in any orientation, but not on iPhone. On iPad when I swipe it just replaces the details view with one that contains the new data. On iOS it pushes, without replacing, a new detail controller.

I don't understand how the same code running on the same OS has this odd behavior. I'm assuming it's a bug that will require some kind of workaround. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to remove tableView:didSelectRowAt: method call since you already telling tableview to select at newIndexPath in one line above.

Comment: So I tried this again today and the error stopped. Not sure why I hadn't changed any code. I've updated my code with your suggestion and posted an update to this thread.

Comment: Its a default behaviour of split view controller. When you attach an segue to detail controller it replaces on ipad and pushed on iphone. If you try running on iphone 6+ size devices in landscape it will behave same as ipad.

Comment: You're right. Ok I'l have to find another way of accomplishing my intended behavior. Thank you.